# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions never called

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The problem seems to have started randomly. 2 days ago, I noticed my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` inside AppDelegate was ignored sporadically/randomly.

Today, it's being ignored on every single run. The app, however, on the simulator is working as normal. I have setup breakpoint on the very first line inside the function and it is never hit, nor are my `NSLog` messages printed.

Can someone please explain what's going on and restore my faith in logic?

Comment: On your debugger do you have the dropdown set to "All output"? If you have it set to any of the others - you may not see your NSLogs.

Comment: Yea it is "All Output". More important is the function being ignored part though :(